# Node: how to check if object Inherits from a constructor by name

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have an object `ObjectC` with the following prototype chain:

`PrototypeC` -> `PrototypeB` -> `PrototypeA` -> `Object`

Where `ObjectC.__proto__ === PrototypeC`

I want to know if `ObjectC` inherits from `PrototypeB` by the actual NAME of the its constructor function (ie. `PrototypeB`).

I do not import `PrototypeC` and therefore cannot use `instanceOf`, `Object.prototypeOf`, etc... as it is part of a 3rd party npm package.

My solution is the following:

```
function _isFromConstructorB(err) {
    return err.__proto__.__proto__ &&
    err.__proto__.__proto__.constructor.name === 'PrototypeB';
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is my method sufficient? The biggest issue I see is that it could potentially break should the prototype chain change.

Comment: I'm not aware of any better way to check this. You can make your function more robust by using a `while` loop to traverse up the prototype chain instead of assuming `PrototypeB` is two levels up. As a side note, `__proto__` is deprecated; you can use `Object.getPrototypeOf()` instead.

Comment: You're right, a while loop would be a great way to generalize this. Thanks!